# XP SP3 chkdsk /i hangs

Tags: hard-drive, windows-xp

We have 1 leftover XP machine that is having some issues.  This computer is a stand alone machine, not hooked up to a network, running some legacy software.  I noticed when trying to access a directory a couple of days ago that the computer locked up, but only that directory.  Other directories and files were fine.  Tried running chkdsk /f and it stopped at checking indexes at 16%.  Left it overnight (10 hours) and was still stuck at 16%.  Tried running chkdsk /i and same result, stuck on checking indexes at 54%.  Tried sfc /scannow and then run chkdsk /i and same result.  Left running 2 hours, still stuck on checking indexes at the exact same percentage as before, 54%.  Tried chkdsk /r and same result, stuck on checking indexes at 54%.

Any suggestions, other than get a new drive?  I plan on letting it run overnight again, but running out of options.

Comment: Check drive's SMART report. Try to limit disk usage to the minimum, if it's a HDD failure then any disk operations can cause irrecoverable data loss. Make sure your backups are up-to-date and restorable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not appropriate to assume the drive is failing. And I can understand the royal pain of an old CNC controller upgrade.

First, you should make sure all the data you need is backed up. Which you indicated is done.

Second, you should determine the health of the drive by doing a surface scan with a 3rd party tool. Several are available and you can use both boot disc based, or windows based tools to test. Here are a few tools or suites that have the capability:

1. MHDD
2. HDD Regenerator
3. HDDScan (I recommend for ease of use and it's free)
4. SeaTools (for Seagate / Maxtor)
5. WD Data Lifeguard (for Western Digital)
6. HD Tune Pro
7. SpinRite (if you go way back like me)
8. Hirens Boot Disc

If you find bad sectors, it may be only one or two and you are good to go. They will be locked out and you can mostly go on with your day. But bad sectors do indicate some physical trouble on the drive, so you may want to do the next step anyways.

Third, if the drive is failing with several bad sectors, stop the test and prepare to clone the drive. You will need to clone the existing drive to a new / used / refurbished drive that is the same type of interface. For instance, if it is IDE then make sure to get an IDE drive. You'll also want to stay as small of a drive as possible at the very least less than 2TB. I say this because it's questionable what XP or your hardware will handle in the range of newer drives. If the drive has many bad sectors, you'll need a tool capable of working with bad sectors during a clone operation:

1. DDRescue
2. DiskPatch

There are probably others, but those are the two I use.

If the drive is not failing with lots of bad sectors you can try any number of other cloning tools:

1. CloneZilla
2. Acronis

If you use any of these other tools, you should pay attention to do a sector-by-sector clone. This will mirror the entire drive including all file system problems so that you can work with it after the clone without losing any data.

Fourth, with a known good drive containing your data, now try to run the following commands in order to try to get past any problems:

1. CHKDSK /C /I /F
2. CHKDSK /I /F
3. CHKDSK /F

Or, just jump right to #3 if you repaired some physical issues on the drive.

Comment: +1, good answer. Just my 2 cents: HDDs have spare sectors and silently recover bad sector as long as spares are available, so if you actually see bad sectors in scans, the drive is almost dead and you should replace it ASAP. SMART should also report number of silently relocated sectors. If it's non-zero, you should already start to worry because more will appear over time (possibly very soon).

Answer (score 1):

So, I was able to get a clone using DiskPatch (other cloning programs did not work) and went ahead and made a backup clone as well.  Then, booted up the 1st cloned disk and everything seemed to be working fine.  So, ran chkdsk /f and there were numerous errors that were found and fixed.  Afterwards, the directory and files that caused the lock up are accessible and, for now, all seems to be good!

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. I'm glad you had success with DiskPatch. I bought it 12 years ago and it saved my butt. I've been upgrading and using it for free ever since and it has recovered dozens of drives for me.

Answer (score 0):

Don't touch the machine for further checks, only backup as soon as you can the remaining data and only AFTER use some recovery tools to see what you can save out of that folder.

The disk is failing and it can only get worse.

Comment: Luckily, the folder that is causing the issue has old data that is backed up.  Folders with newer data have been backed up, so no issues there.  Due to the nature of its use, to get a new drive and install and configure the software will be a royal pain (it is for communicating with CNC controls for transferring machine programs over RS-232 cables)